# Debugging Performance of Spring Cloud Gateway with Netty

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I have Spring Cloud Gateway (Greenwich) running with Netty. This application receives request and then sends request downstream applications depending on the route configuration.

Randomly few request take lot of time(> 70s). Even though the downstream server responded back within 5 sec, Netty threads (reactor-http-epoll-*) are not picking up the response. I have enabled debug logs to see what those threads are doing. From preliminary analysis, it look like those threads are processing something else and are always in runnable state. When this happens the traffic to server is not unusual and it's same as before.

My question here is:

- Why response was not processed by reactor threads while response was received(according to the logging of the downstream app, it sent the response. However, spring-cloud app received response way too late in the logs). Is it possible that all the threads are busy doing other things.
- Is there any run book on how such issues should be investigated?
- Some-places in logs I do see high number of inactive connections in logs but not sure if that is impacting anything. (Channel cleaned, now 56 active connections and 1400 inactive connections)

Any general guidance on how to proceed with investigation to understand why random slowness is happening in application will really help. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I ended up doing below things and after lot of investigation it started working fine for me.

1. Enable logging. Look at how many connections are getting created. In my case, lot of new connections were getting created and and they were not getting re-used.

   io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=paranoid

   logging.level.reactor.netty=DEBUG

   logging.level.reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive=DEBUG

   spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.wiretap=true

   spring.cloud.gateway.httpserver.wiretap=true
2. Make sure there is no blocking code running on reactor-http-epoll-* threads.
3. I upgraded Spring Cloud dependencies from Greenwhich train to latest version of Hoxton train.

Comment: am facing the similar issue what you mentioned here, hope you help on this.
please find the details of what am facing in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71418364/8402445

Comment: FYI: am not seeing any blocked calls on reactor-http-epoll

Comment: So it looks that upgrading Spring Cloud helped, right?