# spring cloud gateway: response time becomes very slow after a while

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

i am using spring cloud gateway and i have 2 custom filters globally.

in which 1 is responsible to read the request body and manipulate and other one is adding access and refresh token to response headers after interacting with keycloak server.

zipkin sleuth config and publishing data to zipkin server via http and 100% of trace info.

any problem here? response times are increasing significantly some times, but not all times.

average every 500 request 10 are getting affected approximately.

using
**Spring Boot 2.6.4** &
**Spring cloud 2021.0.1** & **spring-cloud-starter-gateway: 3.1.1**